# Calculation of the $MO$ homology of $BU$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I am interested in the following calculation:

Let $MO$ be the Thom spectrum of the orthogonal group. Being a spectrum, it defines a generalised homology theory.

Let $BU$ be the direct limit $BU = \displaystyle{\lim_\rightarrow}\,BU(n)$ where $BU(n)$ is the classifying space for the unitary group $U(n)$.

I am able to find calculations for the ordinary homology of $BU$. However, I seem to have problems calculating $MO_*(BU)$.

What I know is that $MO$ is the product of Eilenberg-MacLane spectra, so in principle I think I can relate $MO_*(BU)$ to $H_*(BU)$. However I don't know how to do this directly. I don't know if this has been part of the literature, or something I should be able to calculate myself. Any direction or references are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, $MO$ is a complex oriented (co)homology theory (there is an obvious ring map $MU \to MO$).

For any complex oriented homology theory $E$, the following result holds (reference: Adam's "Stable homotopy and generalised homology", lemma 4.1):

$$E_*(BU)=\pi_*(E)[\beta'_1,\beta'_2,...]$$

This is a polynomial algebra over $\pi_*(E)$ where the $\beta'_i$ are the images of the canonical generators $\beta_i$ of $E_*(\mathbb{C}P^\infty)=\pi_*(E)[\beta_1,\beta_2,...]$ under the map induced by the injection $BU(1)\hookrightarrow BU$. The monomial $\beta'_{i_1}\cdot...\cdot\beta'_{i_r}$ with $0<r\leq n$ is induced by the composite $\underbrace{BU(1)\times...\times BU(1)}_{r\,times}\to BU(r)\to BU(n)\to BU$. Every result mentioned here comes from the fact that the Atiyah–Hirzebruch spectral sequence applied to $BU(n)$ is trivial.

The final calculation reads

$$MO_*(BU)=MO_*[\beta'_1,\beta'_2,...]$$

where $\pi_*{MO}=MO_*$ is well known to be $\mathbb{F}_2[x_i]_{i\not=2^k-1}$.